# How to remove the assertion error in python test code?

Tags: python, json, testing, pytest, assertion

These are the testing methods for prediction

```
def test_get_prediction(input_params, output_params):
  exec_log.info("Testing started for prediction")
  response = aiservice.get_prediction(input_params)
  assert response['predicted_label'] != None
  test_insight(response)

def test_insight(response):

  if('featureImportance' in response['Insight']):
    data_table = response['Insight']['featureImportance']['data']
    assert len(data_table) > 0
  elif(response['Insight'] == 'nearestNeighbors'):
    data_dict = response['Insight']['nearestNeighbors']
    assert len(data_dict) > 0
  elif('modelCoefficients' in response['Insight']  ):
    data_table = response['Insight']['modelCoefficients ']['data']
    assert len(data_table) > 0
```

When I test using pytest in the vs code always gives error as

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
_______________ test_workflow[Classification: Credit Approval] ________________

caplog = <_pytest.logging.LogCaptureFixture object at 0x0000026B1EF15EE0>
test_name = 'Classification: Credit Approval'
test_params = [{'dataImport': {'expectedOutput': {'result': 'success'}, 'input': {'file_location': 'AWS', 
'test_filename': 'credit_d...': 3, 'yAxisLabel': 'Debt', ...}, 'input': {'Age': 30, 'BankCustomer': 
'g', 'Citizen': 'g', 'CreditScore': '1', ...}}}]

  @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_name,test_params", TEST_PARAMS.items(), ids=list(TEST_PARAMS.keys()))
  def test_workflow(caplog,test_name,test_params):

    response = login()

    ai_service = create_ai_service()

    assert response == True
    assert len(ai_service) > 0
    problem_type = ''
    exec_log.info("testing started for " + test_name)
    for stage in test_params:
        for test_key, test_val in stage.items():
            if(test_key == 'dataImport'):
                test_upload_and_import_data(test_val['input'], test_val['expectedOutput'])
            elif(test_key == 'featureEngineering'):
                problem_type = test_feature_eng(test_val['input'], test_val['expectedOutput'])
            elif(test_key == 'training'):
                test_training(test_val['input'], test_val['expectedOutput'], problem_type)
            elif(test_key == "askAI"):
>               test_get_prediction(test_val['input'], test_val['expectedOutput'])

tests\test_pytest.py:87: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

input_params = {'Age': '30.83', 'BankCustomer': 'g', 'Citizen': 'g', 'CreditScore': '1', ...}
output_params = {'insight': 'featureImportance'}

@allure.step
def test_get_prediction(input_params, output_params):
    exec_log.info("Testing started for prediction")
    response = aiservice.get_prediction(input_params)
>   assert response['predicted_label'] != None
E   assert None != None

tests\test_pytest.py:210: AssertionError
```

This always gives the prediction result as

{'statusCode': 400, 'body': '{"predicted_label": null, "Message": "The url you are trying to access is not accepting requests, please check the url provided by Navigator"}', 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}}

I need 'statusCode': 'Completed','body': '{"predicted_label": "+" ........

Comment: Checks for None should be done with  `is` ...

Comment: You get rid of it by ensuring your `response['predicted_label']` is not None.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Tested by   `assert response['predicted_label'] is not None` but same error occurs

Comment: aand? You probably got some test cases where it is None and some where it is NOT None. Now its failing on some other test case. Do you know what asserts are for? Do you know how to debug?

Comment: @PatrickArtner No